# Node - ES Index created without data

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I have been working on a AWS Lambda function to react to a notifications sent by an S3 Bucket each time this one receives logs from Cloudfront. 
I am able to decompress the logs packages and parse them with [Cloudfront Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudfront-log-parser).

However, I am still unable to send them to an ElasticSearch endpoint. I tr mostly with [winston-elasticsearch](https://github.com/vanthome/winston-elasticsearch) and [s3-to-logstore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-to-logstore) but both of them did not work.

Here is my code:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    var srcKey = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

    async.waterfall([
        function fetchLogFromS3(next){
            console.log('Fetching compressed log from S3...');
            s3.getObject({
               Bucket: srcBucket,
               Key: srcKey
            },
            next);
        },
        function uncompressLog(response, next){
            console.log("Uncompressing log...");
            zlib.gunzip(response.Body, next);
        },
        function publishNotifications(jsonBuffer, next) {
            console.log('Filtering log...');
            var json = jsonBuffer.toString();
            console.log('CloudFront JSON from S3:', json);

            var records;
            CloudFrontParser.parse(json, { format: 'web' }, function (err, accesses) {
              if(err){
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                records = accesses;
              }
            });

            // Here, how to send the parsed data? 

            console.log('CloudFront parsed:', records);
        }
    ], function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Failed to send data: ', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Successfully send data.');
        }
        callback(null,"message");
    });
};
```

Is there a simple way to send data to ES? 
 
Something like:

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: process.env.ES_HOST,
  log: 'trace',
  keepAlive: false
});

client.index({
        index: 'cloudfront_index',
        type: 'log',
        body: records
        }, function(err, resp, status) {
        console.log(resp);
});
```

Which works, but does not send the data along:

```
GET cloudfront_index/_search
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You need to use the [`bulk` method](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-bulk) to achieve what you want:

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: process.env.ES_HOST,
  log: 'trace',
  keepAlive: false
});

var bulk = [];
records.forEach(function(record) {
    bulk.push({"index": {}})
    bulk.push(record);
});
client.bulk({
        index: 'cloudfront_index',
        type: 'log',
        body: bulk
}, function(err, resp, status) {
        console.log(resp);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly :)

Comment: Don't forget to call `next`in the bulk callback, though

Comment: `, function(err, resp, status) {
        console.log(resp);
        next();
});` ?